Countdown for New Year's Eve: How do I make a sub-countdown for each 1% that we advance towards the date?
At the time of writing, we are at 29% towards the end of the year. This calculation works fine (see the final variable below). My question is:
How do I get the time that is left until we reach the next 1% (i.e., 30%)? And once we arrive at that point, the time left until it becomes 31%, ...etc?
I know that a percentage increment happens on this scale roughly every three and a half days, exactly 87.6 hours (24*365/100).
Here is my code:


setInterval(function () {
  const dt = new Date();
  document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML =
    ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2) +
    "." +
    ("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    "." +
    dt.getFullYear() +
    " " +
    ("0" + dt.getHours()).slice(-2) + 
    ":" +
    ("0" + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
    ":" +
    ("0" + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
}, 1);

const start = new Date(2023,12,1); 
const end = new Date(2024,12,1);
const today = new Date();
const total = end - start;
let progress = today - start;
const final = Math.round(progress / total * 100 ) + "%"
const finalCalc = document.querySelector("#percentage")
finalCalc.innerHTML = final;
Current time: <span id="datetime"></span><br>
Progress: <span id="percentage"></span><br>
Until next %-increment: <span id="remaining">?</span>



The output I would like to see added and keep updated would be for example:

The next percentage increment will occur in xxx amount of hours

How can I achieve that?

Are you sure you want to use round for your percentage? That would mean you hit 100% before 2024-12-01...

Hi, @veyaks, welcome to the StackOverflow community!!! I could not fully understand what you are looking for... If I am not mistaken, you are trying to create a timer in HTML that counts down to New Year's Eve. That is all clear, now what puts me off is the "100% interval time scale". Does that mean that you want to create a big progress bar that covers the entire screen and counts down towards New Year's Eve? Please, provide clarification on this topic so that we can help you! Maybe you want something like this??

Note that if you pass 12 as second argument to the Date constructor, it is not December, but January of the next year. That argument is 0-based.

@trincot sorry, if my question was unclear. i already have all the variables that display the percentage of the current amount of time we have completed of the year. for example: at this point time we are 29% complete with the year, i wanted to write something that can represent when the next percent will occur but not sure how to write it! i will link a screenshot of what i have right now!

@anmabe i already have variables that show the progress of which we are through the year, right now we are 29% done with the year, but i wanted to make a countdown for each individual percent. for example: "the next percentage will occur in xxx amount of hours". i have the time stamps for when a percentage occurs and it happens every 87.5 hours, so i would want  "xxx" to represent the amount of hours until the next percentage happens and loop everytime. please let me know if this doesn't make sense and i can attach a photo of my markup! apologies, i'm very new to all of this...

Are you sure you want to use round for your percentage? You would hit 100% before reaching the end time, because of that rounding...

@veyaks, I have a solution to your problem!!! I am just waiting for your question to be reopened (I have added some functions for extra clarity + I have made it so that the percentage updates alongside the current time)

@anmabe, I have a solution waiting since the moment the question was closed. I suppose we are not the only ones.

@trincot, do you know who can reopen the question?

@anmabe, you can read about the process here

First of all, realise that new Date(2024,12,1) is the same as new Date(2025,0,1), as the month argument is zero-based.
Secondly, I would not use round in your percentage formula, as that would mean you'd hit 100% about two days before the target date. Use floor instead.
You can take the percentage, add one and then reverse the formula to know at which time the percentage will increase with one unit.
Here is a snippet:


const start = new Date(2024,0,1); 
const end = new Date(2025,0,1);

const outTime = document.querySelector("#datetime");
const outPct = document.querySelector("#percentage");
const outRem = document.querySelector("#remaining");

setInterval(function () {
    const today = new Date();
    outTime.textContent = today.toLocaleString("bg").replace(/ \D+/g, " ");
    if (today >= end) {
        outPct.textContent = "100%";
        outRem.textContent = "";
        return;
    }
    const total = end - start;
    const progress = today - start;
    const pct = Math.floor(progress / total * 100);
    outPct.textContent = pct + "%";
    const next = (pct+1) / 100 * total;
    const countdown = Math.ceil((next - progress) / 1000);
    const hours = Math.floor(countdown / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor((countdown % 3600) / 60);
    const seconds = countdown % 60;
    outRem.textContent = `${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes and ${seconds} seconds`
                         .replace(/\b(1 \w+)s\b/g, "$1");
}, 1);
Current time: <span id="datetime"></span><br>
Progress: <span id="percentage"></span><br>
Until next %-increment: <span id="remaining"></span><br>



It will be hard to test the correctness like this, as it takes a long time before a percentage increase occurs, so maybe use two dates that are closer to each other to do that, like just 1 hour apart (the start of the current hour and the end of it):


const start = new Date();
start.setMinutes(0, 0, 0); // Start of the current hour
const end = new Date();
end.setMinutes(60, 0, 0); // End of the current hour

const outTime = document.querySelector("#datetime");
const outPct = document.querySelector("#percentage");
const outRem = document.querySelector("#remaining");

setInterval(function () {
    const today = new Date();
    outTime.textContent = today.toLocaleString("bg").replace(/ \D+/g, " ");
    if (today >= end) {
        outPct.textContent = "100%";
        outRem.textContent = "";
        return;
    }
    const total = end - start;
    const progress = today - start;
    const pct = Math.floor(progress / total * 100);
    outPct.textContent = pct + "%";
    const next = (pct+1) / 100 * total;
    const countdown = Math.ceil((next - progress) / 1000);
    const hours = Math.floor(countdown / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor((countdown % 3600) / 60);
    const seconds = countdown % 60;
    outRem.textContent = `${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes and ${seconds} seconds`
                         .replace(/\b(1 \w+)s\b/g, "$1");
}, 1);
Current time: <span id="datetime"></span><br>
Progress: <span id="percentage"></span><br>
Until next %-increment: <span id="remaining"></span><br>




You can do this calculation using the millisecond values of the dates
(I'll let you refine this calculation according to your time zone.)


const
  ms_start  = new Date(2024,0,1,0,0,0,0).getTime()  // Milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT
, ms_end_1p = (new Date(2024,11,31,23,59,59,999).getTime() - ms_start) / 100 
  ;
let percentTime = Math.round((Date.now() - ms_start) / ms_end_1p);

console.log( 'percentTime =', percentTime, '%');




I believe the asker already had this calculation in their final variable...

I would make the following adjustments:

Update all stats every ms, not just the current time
Refactor your code into functions so that it is easier for you to make future adjustments
Increase the accuracy of the percentages in your calculations (though they can later be trimmed down) to have an increased accuracy in derived calculations

Taking all of this into account, below is a snippet with these recommendations:


// Constants for all countdowns
const start = new Date(2023,12,1); 
const end = new Date(2024,12,1);
const daysThisYear = daysInYear();
const timeForEntireIncrement = (24*daysThisYear/100);
const currentTimeElement = document.querySelector("#datetime");
const percentageProgressElement = document.querySelector("#percentage");
const timeForIncrementElement = document.querySelector("#remaining");

// This is a helper function to get the exact hours needed for a 1% increase (taking into account leap years and all)
function daysInYear() {
    const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    return new Date(year, 1, 29).getDate() === 29 ? 366 : 365;
}


// This is a helper function to convert the hours left for the next 1% increase in decimal form (i.e., 33.58765 hours) to a format that can be rendered on screen
function convertDecimalHours(decimalHours) {
    var date = new Date(decimalHours * 3600 * 1000);
    var days = Math.floor(decimalHours / 24);
    var hours = (date.getUTCHours()).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false});
    var minutes = (date.getUTCMinutes()).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false});
    var seconds = (date.getUTCSeconds()).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false});
    
    return {
        days: days,
        hours: hours,
        minutes: minutes,
        seconds: seconds
    };
}

// This function solely focuses on rendering the stats into the DOM
function renderStats(currentTime, progress, timeForIncrement){
    currentTimeElement.innerHTML =
        ("0" + currentTime.getDate()).slice(-2) +
        "." +
        ("0" + (currentTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
        "." +
        currentTime.getFullYear() +
        " " +
        ("0" + currentTime.getHours()).slice(-2) + 
        ":" +
        ("0" + currentTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
        ":" +
        ("0" + currentTime.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    //Adjust the X in .toFixed(X) to increase/decrease accuracy of displayed percentage
    percentageProgressElement.innerHTML = progress.toFixed(6) + "%";
    timeForIncrementElement.innerHTML = timeForIncrement.days + " day(s) and " + timeForIncrement.hours + ":" + timeForIncrement.minutes  + ":" + timeForIncrement.seconds;
}

// Loop that updates all stats every ms
setInterval(function () {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    let progress =  (currentTime - start) / (end - start) * 100;
    let decimalTimeForIncrement = timeForEntireIncrement * (Math.ceil(progress) - progress);
    renderStats(currentTime, progress, convertDecimalHours(decimalTimeForIncrement))
}, 1);
<b>Current time:</b> <span id="datetime"></span><br>
<b>Progress:</b> <span id="percentage"></span><br>
<b>Until next %-increment:</b> <span id="remaining">?</span>



Though I have added comments throughout the code, don't hesitate to ask if something feels off!!!
Hope this helped! And may the code be with you...

I am looking at a proposed edit you submitted for the question, where you change 29% to 30%, but even your snippet in this answer displays 29% (which is correct), so I don't think that edit is warranted. Can you check?

Yes, my bad, @trincot, at first I had the numbers rounded up, so that's the reason for the 1% offset. I just fixed it. Nonetheless, the rest of the corrections (the title and some other minor adjustments) are, in my opinion, well-suited since they improve clarity and conciseness.

Great! It has my vote.

@anmabe awesome solution! thank you for taking the time to look at this!

No worries, @veyaks. Always here to help!!!
